# How to give spaces between jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Hi i am trying to make java desktop application where i am using multiple jlabel i want to give little spaces between every label

how can i achieve this

here is my code

```
public class Second extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JLabel label=new JLabel();
    /**
     * Creates new form Second
     */
    public Second() {
          this.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 140, 0));
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
this.setUndecorated(true);
JButton print= new JButton();
print.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 0));
            print.setOpaque(true);
            print.setBounds(525,1282,130,85);
            print.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
          print.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
            print.setText("Print");
            this.add(print);

          JButton home= new JButton();
home.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 0));
            home.setOpaque(true);
            home.setBounds(640,1282,130,85);
            home.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
          home.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255,255 ));
            home.setText("Home");
            this.add(home);

int Height = 134;
int a=100;
             ArrayList<JLabel> label = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

  for(int i=0;i<23;i++){
         JLabel j = new JLabel();
           j.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 140, 255));
            j.setOpaque(true);
            j.setBounds(5,Height,378,50);
            j.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
          j.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(128, 128, 128));
            j.setText("Case                                  Item                         CourtNo   ");
             LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);

       j.setBorder(line);
            this.add(j);
            label.add(j);


               JLabel j1 = new JLabel();
            j1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 140, 0));
            j1.setOpaque(true);
            j1.setBounds(390,Height,768,50);
            j1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
            j1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(128, 128, 128));
            j1.setText("Case                                 Item                         CourtNo   ");
            this.add(j1);
            label.add(j1);


               Height = Height +50;
               a=a+10;
  }




        initComponents();


    }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

         Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
      BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(2);
    Line2D lin1 = new Line2D.Float(386, 100, 386, 1282);
      Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(0, 1283, 768, 1283);
      Line2D line3=new Line2D.Float(400,1284,400,1364);
    g3.setStroke(bs);
     g3.setColor(Color.white);
     g3.draw(lin1);
     g3.draw(lin);
     g3.draw(line3);;

  }
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Second().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }}
```

My new code

```
public class Testing1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Testing1() {

             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = createPanel();
        panel.setLocation(100, 100);
        //panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        initComponents();
    }


     private JPanel createPanel() {
    jPanel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 5));
        EmptyBorder panelBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        jPanel1.setBorder(panelBorder);
        EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(5, 20, 5, 20);
        LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
        CompoundBorder compound = new CompoundBorder(line, border);
        for (int i = 0; i <12; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i);
            label.setBorder(compound);
           // label.setBounds(13, 100, 100, 50);
           jPanel1.add(label);
        }
        return jPanel1;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 306, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 243, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }                      


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Testing1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

updated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read [how to use `LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: _"How to give spaces between jlabel?"_ - `setBounds`: no; Use `EmptyBorders`: yes; Use LayoutManagers with gaps: yes

Comment: @peeskillet..how can i use this can u explain little bit

Comment: add your full code..are you asking about giving spaces between your labels named **Case,Item and CourtNo** ..

Comment: @prakash i have updated my full code

Comment: @user3456343 in this exactly where you need spaces between lables.can you explain clearly..

Comment: when i run this program then it is working

Comment: but i want that when jlabel create at run time it should contain  spaces among every jlabel

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  And yes, all this can be done with the Netbeans GUI builder, if you know how.  Until then, it is ***better to stick with coding by hand.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "How to give spaces between jlabel?"

**`setBounds and null layouts`: no;** Use `EmptyBorders`: YES!; Use `LayoutManagers`: YES!

> "how can i use this can u explain little bit "

Use can use the default [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) of the containing `JPanel` (or in this case set the gaps of the FlowLayout)

**FlowLayout** constructor:

```
public FlowLayout(int align,
      int hgap,
      int vgap)
```

> align - the alignment value
>
> hgap - the horizontal gap between components and between the components and the borders of the Container
>
> vgap - the vertical gap between components and between the components and the borders of the Container

Example

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    panel.add(new JLabel("Label" + i));
}
```

---

You could use [`EmptyBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)

**EmptyBorder** constructor

```
public EmptyBorder(int top,
       int left,
       int bottom,
       int right)
```

> top - the top inset of the border
>
> left - the left inset of the border
>
> bottom - the bottom inset of the border
>
> right - the right inset of the border

Example

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i);
    EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(5, 20, 5, 20);
    label.setBorder(border);
    panel.add(label);
}
```

---

If you want to use a `LineBorder` *and* an `EmptyBorder` for margins, you can use a [`CompoundBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html)

> A composite Border class used to compose two Border objects into a single border by nesting an inside Border object within the insets of an outside Border object. For example, this class may be used to add blank margin space to a component with an existing decorative border:

**CompoundBorder** Example

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(5, 20, 5, 20);
LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
CompoundBorder compound = new CompoundBorder(line, border);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i);
    label.setBorder(compound);
    panel.add(label);
}
```

---

There is an abundant number possibilities. Choose your flavor. The whole point it no *not* try and set size and position to everything, and make use of layout managers and borders and gaps for sizing, spacing etc.

Learn to use the different layout managers at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

---

Full example using **CompoundBorder** and **GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)**

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class CompoundBorderDemo {

    public CompoundBorderDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = createPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5, 10, 10));
        EmptyBorder panelBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.setBorder(panelBorder);
        EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(5, 20, 5, 20);
        LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
        CompoundBorder compound = new CompoundBorder(line, border);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i);
            label.setBorder(compound);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CompoundBorderDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i used compoundborder example it is not creating any jlable at run time

Comment: If you set the layout to null, you have to remove that. null layouts require setting bounds, which I don't recommend

Comment: Also JFrame has a default BorderLayout. You can't just `add` multple components to it, or else only on will appear. Instead add the labels to a panel with its default flowlayout, and add the panel to the frame

Comment: i am not using null layout

Comment: Ok, see my example I just posted

Comment: If you want to add the labels directly to the frame, then you need to change the layout of the frame. You can do so by right clicking on the frame and select Set Layout. Or you can just just drag a JPanel for the frame and set the layout of _that_ panel then add the labels to the panel

Comment: one more question is that  how  can i start creating label from specified location

Comment: You're using a GUI Builder tool, why not just place them manually where you want them? That's what the tool is for. The `GroupLayout` let's you do that. If you want to hand code, then you should use the appropriate layout managers. You can nest multiple panels with different layout managers to get your desired result. Also look into `GridBagLayout` for more precision. Other than that, I can't really offer much more help. If you want exact positioning, you need a null layout where you can set bounds, but I in no way recommend that.

Comment: How can i add jpanel at given position

Comment: You're using the GUI Builder tool aren't you? Just drag and drop it.

Comment: What you want to do with the panel you drag and dropped is just add a new panel to it. The panel you drag and dropped should already have a locastion, so you dont need to set it. Instead set the layout of the panel you dragged to `BorderLayout`. Then create a new JPanel with the method, and add that panel to the one you drag and dropped

Comment: i want to put your given code inside this panel only

Comment: I Know So leave the method the way I had it. Don't change it at all. Then `JPanel panel = createPanel();  jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); jPanel1.add(panel);`

Comment: or `jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`. `BorderLayout` will stretch the `panel` to fit, `GridBagLayout` will respect the preferred size of the `panel`

Comment: Also _why_ are you creating another frame. Your class is already a frame. Take all that frame code out.

Comment: i did this     JPanel panel = createPanel();
        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panel);

Comment: Did you change the method back to how it was? I see in your code that you changed it. And is `jPanel1` the panel that you drag and dropped? It works fine for me. I just tested it with GUI Builder

Comment: i did not make any change in method

Comment: i made change in contructer

Comment: You _DID_ make changes. You changed `JPanel panel` to `jPanel1`, and all the others.

Comment: @peeskillet no s/he waiting for miracle +1

Comment: This will be the last comment I will give you. I am not a help desk, sorry. So **1.** Start _all_ over by creating a new `JFrame` form. **2.** Drag and drop an `JPanel` to it (`jPanel1`) **3.** Copy and paste my method from this answer _exactly_ and don't change it. **4.** in the constructor use `JPanel panel = createPanel(); jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); jPanel1.add(panel);`. That _must_ work, as I have just tested it. Bye and Godspeed.

Comment: @peeskillet  sory to troubled u but i am too much confused can u send more specific code

Comment: i am doing exactly here  is  not workin only  jPanel1.add(panel);

Comment: @peeskillet help me i am getting troubled here                                        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     jPanel1.add(panel);

Comment: You have to do that _after_ `initComponents`. `initComponent` is where `jPanel1` is initialized. Also make sure your panel that you dragged a dropped is actually named `jPanel1`. This is all basic stuff. If you can't figure it out from here, I'm sorry, but I can no longer help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using layouts like GridLayout instead of setting bounds to every label.

it is the simplest solution for your problem.Grid Layout May suit you better.

refer the links below for that..

[**GRID LAYOUT**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)